# how to search for commits for particular issue

Tags: git

i have git repo . Could be a very big source base like Android. There would definetly be fixes to particular issues. I want to know how to search the commits for a particular issue in my whole code base which is a local repo. For linux kernel I probably would have googled and it would give me a patch to apply. how to do this for a local git code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very vague question, since there are many different ways to search your git history - here are a couple of ideas, though:

- If you do: `git log --grep=foo` (for example) you will be shown all commits that have `foo` in the the commit message.  You can use a regular expression with the `--grep` option.
- If you know that a particular string would have been added or removed from the source file when a bug was fixed, you can try (for example) `git log -p -SProblemFactory`, which list all commits with the patch they introduce (`-p`) that changed the number of instance of the string `ProblemFactory` in a particular file.  In recent versions of git you can use the similar `-G` option, which takes a regular expression.